# Graphics Drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I have a Radeon R9 270, where can I get the proper graphics drivers for this card? I've tried a few graphics drivers already but none of them seem to have any affect towards performance and compatibility, specifically with games.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [drivers from AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86#amd-catalyst-packages)?

[image]
<sub>**AMD Graphics Drivers search for Radeon R9 2XX Series**</sub>
<sub>The search result was the AMD Catalyst™ 14.4 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I have tried the graphics drivers that AMD provides but they did not help in terms of performance or compatibility. My games ran very badly and half of them wouldn't even start up and if they did they would crash or freeze my computer a few seconds later.

Comment: The R9 series is relatively new, so I would expect that AMD is focusing it's efforts on optimizing the Windows drivers. Unfortunately, the Linux drivers are not their top priority. If you have Windows, I would recommend using that for gaming, at least until AMD releases better Linux drivers